# Is there a way to inject additional keys into translation table

Tags: angular-translate

I want to create a directive / component which will provide it's own translations to the translate provider. So I wonder if there is a way to manipulate/add keys to the translationTable object within directive. Something like $translatePartialLoader.addPart('{ "MY_TEST_VAR": "This is test"}') to the preferred language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is a discussion about it at 
https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/issues/316.